# What is the fastest way to pick up simple 3D rendering for HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, 3d

I've got a good amount of experience with 2D rendering on `<canvas>`, however there is a project coming up where I need to have a 3D object rotating left along its centre (I believe z-axis). Luckily this is all I need to achieve. The page will run on iPads at an upcoming event.

I'm not experienced with any 3D software/libraries aside from minimal playing around with Papervision 3D in Flash.

I can pick things up pretty easily, so:

1. Are there any frameworks I can use to take care of the initial stuff?
2. Are there any open-source projects that include the code to do the above? If not, tutorials to do it are fine.
3. How do I create the 3D object? Is this the same as a `BitmapMaterial` in Papervision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Threejs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) can be a good library to start with too.

Their ["getting started"](http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/) article is awesome.

Comment: I use three.js also and it is so easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/), for example.

> GLGE is a javascript library intended to ease the use of WebGL; which is basically a native browser javascript API giving direct access to openGL ES2, allowing for the use of hardware accelerated 2D/3D applications without having to download any plugins.
>
> The aim of GLGE is to mask the involved nature of WebGL from the web developer, who can then spend his/her time creating richer content for the web.

Comment: What is a `.obj` file and what software do I need to create them?

Answer (score 1):

Three.js is pretty awesome, just wanted to point you to this github repo as well

http://lamberta.github.com/html5-animation/ check out the examples in part 4.

Billy Lamberta authored [Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430236655), which is a great book teaching you the math/etc. behind doing things like this if you are interesting in getting a little deeper understanding.

Comment: Cheers mate this is really interesting.